# How can I pass a list from another python file to my bottle server?

Tags: python, bottle

I'm struggling with passing a list from a python file to my bottle server. I have split them up into functions so that when you call it they should be printed.

This what I have so far:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, request
import sys
sys.path.append("../python")
from connectedDevices import *

@route('/list')
def print_list():
    # Functions taken from connectedDevices
    get_ip()
    get_mac()
    return template('Forum ID: {{get_ip()}})'), get_ip()=forum_id)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: Maybe this? `return template('Forum ID: {{ip_list}})'), ip_list=get_ip())`

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It doesn't print the content of the function get_ip()

Comment: @mkrieger1 have you tried the solution I've put?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, apparently if I use functions from the input file I couldn't call variables independently, only the function lot. I removed them so now I can call the list and used this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    info={'iplist': iplist, 'maclist': maclist, 'signallist': signallist, 'hostlist': hostlist}
    tpl = '''
    <table>
    %for i in range(len(maclist)):
        IP Address: {{iplist[i]}}
    <br/>
        MAC Address: {{maclist[i]}}
    <br/>
        Signal: {{signallist[i]}}
    <br/>
        Hostname: {{hostlist[i]}}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    %end
    </table>
    '''
    return template(tpl, info)
```